# How to set initial values for ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set the initial values for a field in my form :

```
class EspecialidadesForm(forms.Form):
    especs = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Especialidade.objects.all())
```

My View:

```
especs_form = EspecialidadesForm(initial={'especs':salao.especialidades})
```

'especialidades' field is a ManyToManyField field.

Template :

```
{{ especs_form.especs }}
```

Its returns me

'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A many-to-many field is a manager, you need to call `.all`:

```
especs_form = EspecialidadesForm(initial={'especs':salao.especialidades.all()})
```